# docker build fails on Google Container-optimized OS versions cos-beta-67 and newer

Tags: google-container-os

Unable to "docker build" on COS beta-67 and dev-68. Works on stable-65. Not sure if this is on purpose or is a bug.

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM alpine:6.7

$ docker build -t foo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF
```

Comment: You are calling alpine version 6.7 as far as I can see the last version is 3.7 so just modify it